# Vue - Disable dropdown if other dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two dropdown menus and I want the user to only be able to select an option if the other is not selected. I'm converting from Razor pages to Vue so I need to do it in Vue.

This is what the Razor page looks like:
[image: Razor]

And this is what the Vue page I made currently looks like:
[image]

I've got it to sort of work - but I just want it to be temporarily disabled if one of the dropdowns is selected, not removed entirely.
[Here's the fiddle](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNq1U8FOwzAM/RWTAwKJtfdqICEE4sAkpB04UA5Z620ZbRI5acc09d9x07XayuCGVLXxs/38ktfsxb21UV2hSMTUY2kL6fEu1QBThwVmHupJaXIsblNhNKYCGFBLji781qQilHKxsV4ZzbmlIU66arFpm5WGw9INtQD7fY9C0xwI4o6hGx13s3/REQYPMoKq/5cRgFzVh+55yGCeMAsraBr+sq6OZxp3hdP46EQ5dBkp29LhlzXkIcelrAoP+7Ypl15eXXdrAEJfke4jGOQn8N5DrEk85lUmW8GpuDnBM6NNqTLe7imuV4Vy6/MoXMIDIdPVCG+kvNKrUeEToc7G3c/KeUM7RrtT6vEXuR1VziR94hnamfRrLHlw0HvK8up22doUZhUGHGfmVuqwlx78GEjZkYQrjsawNydI8Ilf/LDNvS/iRqiytWZSShttnNF8LYIH6SHBAtnyjiMVfG/aOBVr761L4tgts/YybVxkaBXzKqJKe1VihK6cLMhsHRITDzoCB/9nVCNN+HRzJKS/OEelP3j7fYnmG1a/NTs=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong the example below will solve the problem. Also [check here for demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

You can feel free to make selection from both dropdowns. If one is selected other one will be deselected.

```
<template>
  <select @change="changeHandler('one')" v-model="one"  >
    <option v-for="subject in subjects">
      {{ subject }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <select @change="changeHandler('two')" v-model="two" >
    <option v-for="subject in subjects">
      {{ subject }}
    </option>
  </select>
  
  <div>
    Selected: {{one}} {{two}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      subjects: [
        "Education",
        "Economics",
        "English",
        "English & Creative Writing",
        "French",
        "History",  
        "Law",
        "Marketing",
        "Mathematics",  
        "Psychology", 
        "Spanish"
      ],
      one: "",
      two: "",
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeHandler(param) {
      if(param === 'one') {
        this.two = "";
      } else {
        this.one = ""
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using v-if you can use select's disable attribute or conditional class binding. [Here is a codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-cdn-9upctw?file=/src/App.vue)

```
<select v-model="one" :disabled="!!two">
      <option v-for="(subject, index) in subjects" :key="index">
        {{ subject }}
      </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Using `Boolean(val)` rather than `!!` better expresses the intent

Comment: Hmm, that's close to what I want. But I still want the user to be able to select the other dropdown if they choose. Just not both at the same time. Perhaps I have to do a radio button for that?